# Fluxor Blazor error on assembly scanning and registration

Tags: c#, redux, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluxor

I've followed the steps of setting up a Fluxor library.

Added
`var currentAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly; builder.Services.AddFluxor(options => options.ScanAssemblies(currentAssembly));`

into the Program.cs. Then added `<Fluxor.Blazor.Web.StoreInitializer/>` into App.Razor

Stater is decorated with `[FeatureState]` attribute. Everything according to documention. But the application fails to start with the message :

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Store.Account.AccountTopUpState

Seems like the problem exists in Fluxor assembly scanning ...

Answer (score 2):

Are you also creating a class deriving from `Feature<AccountTopUpState>`? If so, remove the `[FeatureState]` attribute. I believe the [attribute was added](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/issues/204) as an alternative to the Feature base class approach, and you should choose one approach or the other, but not both.

Comment: I endorse this product and/or solution :)